# Invalid syntax error at the "kapfun(i)" line in the "createlist" function

Tags: python

I keep getting an invalid syntax error at the `kapfun(i)` line in the `createlist` function. Can anyone tell me why?

```
def createlist(i):
    n=i
    global n
    a=n[0:1]
    b=n[1:2]
    c=n[2:3]
    d=n[3:4]
    n=[int(a),int(b),int(c),int(d)

    kapfun(i)
    return i

def kapfun(i):                  
    print(i)
    kaprekar=down(i)-up(i)    
    return kaprekar

def integer(numList):                              
    integer= ''.join(map(str, numList))
    return int(integer)

def up(n):                                   
    n.sort()
    up=n 
    up=integer(up)

    return up

def down(n):                    
    print(n)
    n.reverse()
    down=n
    down=integer(down)

    return down

def kaprekarfunction(i):               
    createlist(i)
    print (i)
    kapfun(i)
    print (i)
    return i

x="1234"
createlist(x)
print(x)
```

Comment: For future reference: When you get a `SyntaxError` in a line that looks perfectly good, look upward—it's almost always a missing `)`, `]`, or `}` on a previous line. The first time you make this mistake, you will spend hours banging your head on the wall before finding it. The 100th time, you'll find it immediately. (But you'll never stop making the mistake…)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the bracket at the end of your list on the previous line.  It should be:

```
n=[int(a),int(b),int(c),int(d)]
```